# Which transformation is better for a PCA?

Tags: pca, data-transformation

I'm analyzing morpho-functional indices of forelimbs in a subterranean rodent (e.g. olecranon length / ulna length x 100) and I don't know how to treat data prior to a PCA. Which transformation is better? Natural logarithm, log10, angular transformation, or no transformation?

Comment: Could you give us an idea as to the distribution of the measurements you have taken? Perhaps a histogram or kernel density plot might help to know if the data needs to be transformed at all.

Comment: I'm traying to find the link for loading files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information would help a lot, but there is a simple tentative answer from what you have told us.

In principle a ratio of lengths must be positive and is likely to be skew in distribution, but its logarithm will usually be (much?) more nearly symmetric in distribution.

PCA is just a transformation procedure, but putting in data that are approximately symmetric in distribution will often make patterns (much?) easier to see.

There is no difference statistically between log10 and ln. Go with what's easier to explain to your audience: do zoologists know about natural logarithms?

Angular transformation applies only to bounded measurements. If it's necessarily true that a length ratio must be within (0,1) -- i.e. it is anatomically inevitable that one bone or whatever must be shorter than another -- then angular is possible, but it may be that logit is better.

Comment: ooh, thanks a lot (i will try to give more information using my poor English). Specifically, i'm analyzing postnatal changes in different forelimb proportions (e.g. humerus robustness, epicondilar relative width, etc). Thus, i'm comparing three age groups: infants, juveniles and adults. I analyzed these indices using MANOVA (where variables were transformed in this way: p'=asen(squareroot(p)) and now, i want to explore the data set using a PCA, but i'm a little confused about how to use data... :)

Comment: On angular transformation, arcsine(square root) which is what you have, check out http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/10-0340.1

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot Nick. I'm logit-transforming my data now! After some reading i think that is better too. 
Thanks for your time!
:)

Comment: (Especially, after reading the pdf you recommended me)